# Please explain how the following recursive code is evaluated?

Tags: c, recursion

```
void fun(int n)
{
    if(n > 0) {
        fun(--n); 
        printf("%d", n);
        fun(--n);
    }
}
```

How is the following code evaluated? It gives the output as 0 1 2 0

Comment: That code does nothing since it's just a function. how is the function called? Also, is this homework? And have you tried to understand it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458724/please-explain-how-the-following-recursive-code-is-evaluated for more info

Comment: I'm surprised it runs at all since it's missing a }

Comment: Try tracing it by hand to see.

Comment: You forget to close `{`

Comment: It's evaluated as invalid code: there's a mismatched curly brace.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun(3) //n=3
    func(2) // n = 3, (--n) = 2
        func(1) // n = 2, (--n) = 1 
            func(0) // n = 1, (--n) = 0
            printf("%d", 0) // n=0   **Got 0 **
            func(-1) // n = 0, (--n) = -1

        printf("%d",1) // n = 1      **Got 0 1** 
        func(0) // n = 1, (--n) = 0


    printf("%d", 2) // n =2           "Got 0 1 2"
    func(1) // n = 2, (--n) = 1
        func(0) // n = 1, (--n) = 0
        printf("%d", 0) // n=0       ***Got 0 1 2 0*
        func(-1) // n = 0, (--n) = -1
```